# Android network security configuration not working

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate

I have network_security_config.xml file:

```
<domain-config >
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">*.my.com</domain>
    <pin-set>
        <pin digest="SHA-256">ynukivptnymykhmh9ykymhnffgkhkyyjnyjykhdggrg=</pin>
        <pin digest="SHA-256">eufhhvvaeqpfkgnghdgsfsebefhedswywtfvnrnjryu=</pin>
  </pin-set>
</domain-config>
```

in Androidmanifest.xml:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

SSLSocketFactory implementation:

```
public class ClientSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public ClientSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore, boolean strict) throws  KeyStoreException {
        super(truststore);
        TrustManager trustManager;
        if (strict) {
            trustManager = new EasyX509TrustManager(truststore);
        } else {
            trustManager = new NaiveTrustManager();
        }
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, new SecureRandom());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

}
```

but this security configuration doesn't work. For example, if I will set error certificzte keys or error domain, I don't get any exception. I think it is because of my app doesn't check sertificates. Why?

Comment: Do you use `strict` mode of ClientSSLSocketFactory? If not why do you disable certificate checking and instead activate pinning? Pining is always only an additional measure. Certificate checking should never be disabled!!!

Comment: I use strict  `ClientSSLSocketFactory`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the example provided in Andorid documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CertificatePinning

As you can clearly see your domain `*.my.com` is specified wrong. There are no wildcards to be used in `domain>` elemnt. The wildcard is implicitly defined by the attribute `includeSubdomains="true"`.

So this is the full `network_security_config.xml` file you should use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config >
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">ynukivptnymykhmh9ykymhnffgkhkyyjnyjykhdggrg=</pin>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">eufhhvvaeqpfkgnghdgsfsebefhedswywtfvnrnjryu=</pin>
      </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But doesn't change: if I set proxy I can sniffing via charles.

Comment: @Monica What device do you use for testing?

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy A51

Comment: Then it should work. Make sure to use the full network_security_config.xml content of my updated answer. What HTTP client do you use in your app and do you override the TrustManager implementation?

Comment: I use Apache HttpClient and added in question SSLSocketFactory implementation.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, I'm facing same issue

Comment: @IslamAssem Sorry but it is unclear what `this` is in your context. Which comment is it you are answering?

Comment: I mean ssl pinning not working even if I put wrong sha, it blocks only webview pages but doesn't block api requests

Comment: @IslamAssem Than your app is most likely not a plain Java/Kotlin app. Pinning is only active if the Java API für HTTPS connections is used. If your app uses a framework that has an own HTTP implementation then of course pinning will not be active because third party framework usually ignore Android pinning specification.